# Why would a site such as Craigslist not accept pre-paid debit cards?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card

I tried to post a classified ad on Craigslist and found that they do not accept pre-paid debit cards.

Why could that be?

Comment: Because it's as much about identifying you as about payment.  If a card is used for unacceptable stuff they know who you are and can decide if they want to let you post another ad or not.  A pre-paid card is anonymous, they can't flag you with it.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer He's not looking for a product or service recommendation, but rather to understand a rule.

Comment: @LorenPechtel you should post your first comment as an answer!

Comment: Reopened. My knee-jerk reaction was that it was a specific question about one company, not really a PF question. I edited wording to make it general, as it's not really about that one company. I agree with Vicky, you should post the comment as an answer.

Comment: @Vicky You can't post answers on locked questions.  Now that it's reopened I posted it as an answer.

Comment: You need to clarify the question.  The original made it seem as though you were trying to sell the cards. via a classified ad.  This revision seems like you are trying to use the card to pay for posting a classified ad, but the service mentiond in the original doesn't charge for posting - or didn't as of a year or so ago.

Comment: @jamesqf Craigslist does charge for certain types of ads.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer What's wrong with a mention of Craigslist? If you won't allow a question specifically about Craigslist, why won't you allow it to be even mentioned as an example?

Comment: Ben, my opinion, in general, the mention of specific companies is not needed if the issue is general, and probably off topic if it only applies to that one company. When I read this it struck me as OP asking us to guess the motivation of this company's rules. But if the issue is common, then it deserves an answer.

Comment: If you feel that approach is wrong, I can reverse my edit. I'm not adamant on this one. I'd respect and go with your view if you feel strongly...

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I do feel that approach is wrong.  See [this](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2155/10997), [this](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2159/10997), and [this](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997).  Even you once asked a [question about Ticketmaster](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/64445/10997).  :)

Comment: Understood, and rolled back. As always, your input is valued. And you have a great memory, I am getting old.

Answer (score 11):

Because it's as much about identifying you as about payment. If a card is used for unacceptable stuff they know who you are and can decide if they want to let you post another ad or not. A pre-paid card is anonymous, they can't flag you with it.